# DAX - YTD with year on columns

Tags: dax

Can anybody suggest how to write YTD Sales formula in DAX that can be used (e.g. in Excel Pivot Table) with Year on column, to compare YTD sales over the last few years.

Specifically, my difficulty is in determining "as of date". If I refer to the `Date` table without removing the filter, then something like `LASTNONBLANK('Date'[Date],[SalesAmount])` will give me `12/31` of the corresponding year for prior year's columns. And if I remove the Date filter via `ALL()` I will get the last available date, thus ignoring filters/slicers a user may have added.

I am fairly new to DAX, and was hoping that this was a common scenario that someone has already solved. But all I am finding are the solutions for YTD comparison with prior year, NOT YTD "trend" over multiple years.

Any feedback is really appreciated!

Vlad

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details for me to be specific, but I can guess at your dataset.

Assuming:

```
table1 with Date, Period, Year and SalesAmount
```

AND

```
table2 with Period and Year
```

AND

```
No relationships.
```

Your measures might go like this:

```
MAX_PERIOD = CALCULATE(MAX(table2[Period]))

MAX_YEAR = CALCULATE(MAX(table2[Year]))

YTD Sales = Calculate(Sum([SalesAmount]), FILTER(table1, table1[Period] <= [MAX_PERIOD] && table2[Year] = [MAX_YEAR]))
```

And your Pivot Table/Matrix might look like this:

```
_____________________________
|Filters:    |Columns:      |
|            |table2[Period]|
|            |              |
|____________|______________|
|Rows:       |Values:       |
|table2[Year]|[YTD Sales]   |
_____________________________
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually I just have table1 with Date (from which I can derive Year) and Amount. And I could not figure out a way from within YTD formula whether there is any filter on Date coming from filter/slicer. E.g. how to know if a user, for example, set a filter to Date<=5/31/18, so that display YTD amount as of 5/31 for each year. The only workaround I could think of is to introduce disconnected table2 storing day_of_year (with label), just to use it to filter "as of day" for YTD calculation. Then I can do MAX_DAY_OF_YEAR = CALCULATE(MAX(table2[day_of_year])) and go from there.

Comment: Precisely. The Same idea keeps trickling down. Just add '&& table1[Date]<=[Date]'